# PHP interprets numbers as floats even when they're less than INT_MAX

Tags: php, integer-overflow

PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow) states that:

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

**But what about an operation which results in a number less than PHP_INT_MAX ?**

See this code snippet as an example:

```
$max_int = 2**31-1 ; //  2147483647
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX === $max_int); // false
```

As you can see, even when an operation results in a valid int value PHP seems to cast the result into float

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX === (int) $max_int) // true
```

**My questions:**

Does PHP interpreter cast the result into float before making any calculations?

Shouldn't PHP calculate the result and then sets the type accordingly? (Makes sense right?)

**Edit:**

PHP version: 7.2.1 32-bit

OS: Windows: 10 x64

I'm using XAMPP

Comment: Do you know is the value of `PHP_INT_MAX`?

Comment: @FatalError, I'm not sure that it happens like that for lesser integers. Please have a look here: https://3v4l.org/S9hmd Could you also provide more info about the environment (os, PHP version) where this was happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calculating `$max_int = 2**31-1` the engine does this in steps:

```
$tmp = 2**31;
$max_int = $tmp-1
```

Here `$tmp` is bigger than maximum integer value and converted to a floatng point number. In consequence there is an float subtraction, resulting in  a float. Since it had been float it has to stay float.